# Google Webmaster: Crawl Stat Increase, but Index status stay flat for days

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

Back in June, my website experienced a significant drop in index status from 73,000 to 36 and my website cannot be found in Google search.

[image: Index Status]
A few days ago, a friend programmer fixed the problem that might have caused this problem (apparently there is a code inside the website that is blocking Google bot) and it is already appearing in the search result. One thing I don't understand is the Index status is still flat at 36, but the crawl stat has spiked in the last couple of days. 
[image: Crawl Stats]
What does this mean? I thought the Index status should go up again since my website and its links are now appearing in Google search result. Please help me understand and how I can get to the 70,000 level before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I will start with the harsh part of the message followed by the good news.

Just because Google spiders your site does not mean that it will index it.

Harsh huh? But true. Sometimes.

But now for the good news.

Your site, short of a penalty, will be indexed. Once the a page is spidered, it is parsed and then placed into the index. But since your site has been de-listed due to a code error, as you said, it may take a bit longer before your site gets listed in the SERPs. Google is being somewhat cautious. I suspect they are comparing your site now versus before and recalculating any metrics for your site. It is likely that a good sample of your site will be taken before there is any real movement. I suspect that if your site compares well, your site will be indexed rather quickly just as before.

The reason why I say *suspect* is, I rather believe that Google is going to treat this like a site outage. It will work out I promise. It will take time to re-include your site in the index though and your performance will ramp up over time too. So be patient. It can take a while.

Now that is better!

Also, please understand that Google Webmaster Tools is far from real-time. Most metrics lag 2 days behind and others may lag more. So use it as a guide. But do not place any bets.

Comment: Thanks so much closetnoc! I'll give it more time and see how it goes. Do you have any advice to speed up the process? Perhaps adding more useful content? My website is ecommerce.

Comment: There is no way to speed up Google and they seem to get p1553d when you try. Just make sure your site is up and available and that you do not make too many changes and freak them out. You can add content of course, but do not make SEO changes and what not that can make them nervous or think they need to recalculate your metrics.